# Android fast bitmap drawing

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I need to optimize this portion of code which consume about 70ms (on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 - Android 7.0):

```java
private static final int IR_FRAME_WIDTH = 160;
private static final int IR_FRAME_HEIGHT = 120;

...

final int[] bmp_data = NormalizeBmp(image_data, IR_FRAME_WIDTH, IR_FRAME_HEIGHT, Polarity.WhiteHot);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(IR_FRAME_WIDTH, IR_FRAME_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

final Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

for (int y = 0; y < IR_FRAME_HEIGHT; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < IR_FRAME_WIDTH; x++) {
        final int _gray = bmp_data[(y * IR_FRAME_WIDTH) + x];

        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(_gray, _gray, _gray));
        canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
    }
```

I'm not used to native code so I would prefer not-to use it if there's a standard code way to improve this performances.
I think the code is pretty self-explaining `NormalizeBmp` create an array of 160x120 integers containing the gray tone to use. I can easily change `NormalizeBmp` to produce a different color output.

Comment: Why not create a bitmap from the bmp_data and draw it over the canvas in one go, instead of drawing each point on the canvas?

Comment: @RahulShukla my very first answer should be _because I don't know how to do it_: :-) . I tried with several attempts to use either `canvas.drawBitmap()` or  `createBitmap()` feeding them with `bmp_data` but without success and a number of exceptions thrown. Another minor problem is that `bmp_data` is currently filled with just an integer value representing the gray value if had to feed such procedures with `bmp_data` I suppose it should be filled with 3 integers per pixel (red, green and blue).

Comment: See this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)

For the "3" integer per pixel, you can modify the NormalizeBitmap function to pack (aRGB) values in the single integer by using 
int realGrayValue = retval[0];
int color = (0xFF<<24 | realGrayValue << 16 | realGrayValue<<8 | realGrayValue)
retVal[0] = color

Comment: or more simply
retVal[i] = Color.valueOf(retVal[i], retVal[i], retVal[i], 255); ///(R,G,B,a)

Comment: uhm I got what you suggest but `Color.valueOf()` return a `Color` value not an `int`

Comment: Anyway I just followed your first hint and did it _bitwise_. It works thnx 70ms -> 2ms I think it's a good result.

Comment: So should I write that as an answer to accept that? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of drawing pixel by pixel over the canvas, what you can do is to create a bitmap directly from the data returned by NormalizeBmp(). All you need is to modify the returned int array to pack the colors in RGB format. Since you are using the same color to set your Paint() in RGB, this would be pretty straightforward. Here's a simple way to pack the color:

```
retVal[i] = (0xFF << 24) | (retVal[i] & 0xFF)<< 16 | (retVal[i] & 0xFF) << 8 | retVal[i]
```

and then use the modified array to draw a bitmap using [Bitmap.Create(int[] colors, width, height, bitmap_format).](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config))